# Google Cast a Video with Audio overlay

Tags: android, cordova, google-cast

I am developing a hybrid mobile application (using Ionic 2) that allows users to overlay audio on a video. Essentially, the video and audio track are able to play at the same time. The challenge is getting this behavior with Google Cast functionality – I want the user to be able to Cast the video as well as the separate audio overlay to their Cast device.

I’ve decided to develop a custom Cordova plug-in (starting with Android) that implements the Google Cast API natively for the following reasons: Google Cast Web API depends on the Chrome browser so our hybrid app running in Cordova’s WebView won’t work, and the most up-to-date Cordova plugin that I have seen A) doesn’t implement this audio overlay functionality and B) appears to be abandoned since Sept 2015.

That’s the background, now the question.

How I understand it so far, generally the Cast API works by sending the Receiver Application a URI, and the Receiver Application takes care of fetching this resource either from a server or from the Sender app’s resources. This poses a problem for me: my application utilizes two resources simultaneously.

I saw [here](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender/advanced#use_media_tracks) that MediaInfo can represent a grouping of MediaTracks, which could be audio, video, text…etc. Am I able to have multiple MediaTracks active at the same time? Should I be exploring custom implementations in a Custom Receiver App to enable multiple active MediaTracks?

Should I look into demuxing the mp4, mixing the audio streams and muxing into a separate, temporary mp4 file, and handing the URI of this temp mp4 off to the Cast Device?

I’m in the research phase right now, but will be implementing and testing various solutions over the next few weeks. What other creative solutions can anyone think of? Has anyone done this before? And lastly, can anyone say for **certain** that this cannot be done?

Any help/advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Cast SDK on the receiver doesn't support more than one active media element, so even if you write a custom receiver and include two media elements, one for video and one for audio, only one can be active at a time, so that is not going to work. If you can mix them into one mp4, then that is going to be the best approach and can work with Default or Styled receivers as well (hence no need to write a custom one).